# How often is React changing on CDN (unpkg.com)

Tags: reactjs

I am using React JS library in my HTML pages, and for vulnerabilities reason I have to use `integrity` attribute:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" integrity="sha256-hXNk4rmCMYQXAl+5tLg1XAn3X6RroL6T9SD3afZ1eng=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" integrity="sha256-bRHakm3eFVwNh3OuDgW7ZGg/H0DU4etihxfdhJkXIoI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Is it OK to use `integrity` attribute and check hash? If the original file changes, hash will change too and library will not downloaded.

Comment: If you're going to do that you need to pin the exact version, not just "18".

Comment: @jonrsharpe are you talking about this? https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js, https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js

Comment: Yes, otherwise exactly the problem you mention will happen - `18.2.1` or `18.3.0` will release with a new hash and your page will refuse to load it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the `integrity` attribute, as this is the intended use. However, as you already pointed out the hash will change with every version update. So in order to not break the integrity, you will need to fix your import to a specific version like this.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.1/umd/react.development.js" integrity="sha256-hXNk4rmCMYQXAl+5tLg1XAn3X6RroL6T9SD3afZ1eng=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.1/umd/react-dom.development.js" integrity="sha256-bRHakm3eFVwNh3OuDgW7ZGg/H0DU4etihxfdhJkXIoI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This will however not provide you with new versions of React, if there are security updates or patches but therefore also has no risk of breaking your code.

Find more information about the integrity attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

Talking about unpkg.com, technically any urls without a specific version number are forwarded to one with a specific version number to ensure proper caching mechanisms. Find more information about this [here](https://unpkg.com).